# Group Multiple Objects Based on Type Using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

I want to group `unordered-list-item` and `ordered-list-item`.

Below is the original structure:

```
{
  data: {
    areas: [{
      sections: [{
        rjf: [
          {
            type: "unordered-list-item",
            text: "Item 1",
          },
          {
            type: "unordered-list-item",
            text: "Item 2",
          },
          {
            type: "paragraph",
            text: "This is text",
          }]
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Now I want to group all list items into a new object.

So the expected structure is:

```
{
  data: {
    areas: [{
      sections: [{
        rjf: [
          {
            type: "list",
            items: [{
              type: "unordered-list-item",
              text: "Item 1",
            },
            {
              type: "unordered-list-item",
              text: "Item 2",
            }]
          },
          {
            type: "paragraph",
            text: "This is text",
          }]
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

So I wanted to move all the `unordered-list-item and ordered-list-item` to `items` array and the following object `type` like `paragraph` shouldn't be impacted.

I created a solution in TypeScript, but the code was too long:

```
const areas = data.areas;
      const listItemTypes = ['unordered-list-item', 'ordered-list-item'];
      return areas.map(area => {
        return area.sections.map(section => {
          let lastHeadingIndex = -1;
          return section.rjf.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
            if (!current.type || !listItemTypes.includes(current.type)) {
              lastHeadingIndex = acc.length;
              return [...acc, current];
            }
            let listObject = acc.find((el, i) => i > lastHeadingIndex && i < index && el.type === 'list');
            if (!listObject) {
              listObject = {
                type: 'list',
                items: [current]
              };
              return [...acc, listObject];
            }
            listObject.items = [...listObject.items, current];
            return acc;
          }, []);
        });
      });
```

**How can I achieve the same functionality using lodash?**

****UPDATE****

I tried with lodash, but dosen't seems to work.

```js
var content = {
  data: {
    areas: [{
      sections: [{
        rjf: [{
            type: "unordered-list-item",
            text: "Item 1",
          },
          {
            type: "unordered-list-item",
            text: "Item 2",
          },
          {
            type: "paragraph",
            text: "This is text",
          }
        ]
      }]
    }]
  }
};

var result = content.data.areas.map((area => {
    return area.sections.map(section => {
       section.rfj = _.groupBy(section.rfj, 'type');
    });
}));

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, '  ') + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you okay with mutating the input or do you want a new object?

Comment: I wanted a new object

Answer (score 0):

```
return data.areas.map((area => {
    return area.sections.map(section => {
       return section.rfj = _.groupBy(section.rfj, 'type')
    })
})
```

You may need some more little tweaking on the result if you need a more specific structure, but this should do most of the work

Comment: Yeah `data.` at the beginning is wrong. It should be `content.data.areas(...`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code to something like this.

- Use nested `map` on `areas` and `sections`.
- You are returrning the arrays from both `map`. Return objects with `sections` and `rjf` property instead (Assuming both structures are objects with just one property)
- When looping through `rjf`, create 2 arrays: `items` and `others`
- Group each object to these 2 arrays based on whether `types` array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the current object's `type`.
- Create an array with one `list` object (`{ type: "list", items }`) and remaining objects from `others` array

```js
const types = ['unordered-list-item', 'ordered-list-item'],
      input = {data:{areas:[{sections:[{rjf:[{type:"unordered-list-item",text:"Item 1",},{type:"unordered-list-item",text:"Item 2",},{type:"paragraph",text:"This is text",}]}]}]}}

const areas = input.data.areas.map(a => {
  return {
    sections: a.sections.map(s => {
      const items = [], others = [];
      
      s.rjf.forEach(o =>
        types.includes(o.type) ? items.push(o) : others.push(o)
      )

      return { rjf: [{ type: "list", items }, ...others] }
    })
  }
})

console.log({ data: { areas } })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another approach by copying each object leven and map all arrays and group the last level by using a function for grouping.

This approach uses am iter function which gets all functions for each level and the starting object.

At the end, it returns a new object with the given structure and the grouped items.

```js
function copy(source, fn) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object
        .entries(source)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: fn(v) }))
    );
}

function map(array, fn) {
    return array.map(fn);
}

function group(array) {
    var items;
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (listItemTypes.includes(o.type)) {
            if (!items) {
                items = [];
                r.push({ type: 'list', items });
            }
            items.push(o);
        } else {
            items = undefined;
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

function iter([fn, ...fns], object) {
    return fn ? fn(object, iter.bind(null, fns)) : object;
}    

var object = { data: { areas: [{ sections: [{ rjf: [{ type: "unordered-list-item", text: "Item 1" }, { type: "unordered-list-item", text: "Item 2" }, { type: "paragraph", text: "This is text" }] }] }] } },
    listItemTypes = ['unordered-list-item', 'ordered-list-item'],
    result = iter([copy, copy, map, copy, map, copy, group], object);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```